# Concat and minify Bootstrap js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

I'm using Bootstrap to scaffold a project and Grunt to build the files for production.

Should I concat and minify the js files.

I've tried doing this but the js files stop working.

A little more explanation:

I'm developing a Wordpress theme using Bootstrap and Grunt to minify the css and js for production.

I have a dev-theme and a dist-theme.

In the dev-theme I have js folder with the bootstrap js and a project.js file that contains my js for the theme.

Using the dev-theme in Wordpress my project.js works(a simple test alert on page load).

In the grunt file I am concatenating all the js files together in complete.js. This works and I have one files that contains all the js.

I'm then minifing the js and copying it to the dist-theme to produce complete.min.js.

In the dist-theme I am referencing the complete.min.js but my alert isn't working anymore.

The dev-theme js folder also contains moderniser which works in the dev-theme but after concatenation and minifying doesn't work in the dist-theme.

My grunt file.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt){

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        yeoman:{
            dev: 'dev-theme',
            dist: 'dist-theme'
        },

        jshint: {
      files: ['dev-theme/js/*.js'],//all files with .js
      options: {
        // options here to override JSHint defaults
        globals: {
          jQuery: true,
          console: true,
          module: true,
          document: true
        }
      }
    },

        sass:{
            dist:{
                files:{
                    'dev-theme/css/styles.css' : 'dev-theme/css/bootstrap.scss'
                }
            }
        },

        cssmin : {
            css:{
            src: 'dev-theme/css/styles.css',
        dest: 'dist-theme/css/styles.min.css'
        }
    },

        concat:{
            dist:{
                src:['dev-theme/js/**/*.js'],
                dest:'dev-theme/js/complete.js'
            }
        },

        uglify : {
            js: {
                src: ['dev-theme/js/complete.js'],
        dest: 'dist-theme/js/complete.min.js'
      }
        },

        watch:{

            css:{
                files: 'dev-theme/css/**/*.scss',
                tasks:['sass'],
                options:{
                    livereload: true
                }
            },

            js:{
                files:'dev-theme/js/**/*.js',
                tasks:['jshint'],
                options:{
                    livereload: true
                }
            }

        },

        clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    //'.tmp',
                    'dist-theme/*',
                                        //don't clean
                                        '!dist-theme/style.css',
                                        '!dist-theme/screenshot.png',
                                        '!dist-theme/functions.php',
                ]
            }]
        }
    },


        copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: 'dev-theme',
                dest: 'dist-theme/',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'images/{,*/}*',
                                        'fonts/{,*/}*',
                    '{,*/}*.html',
                                        '{,*/}*.php',

                                        //don't clean
                                        '!functions.php',
                ]
            }]
        }
    }                       
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
    grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean:dist','cssmin','concat','uglify','copy:dist']);
    grunt.registerTask('webfont', ['webfont']);

}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting, what does the minified file look like? What you are attempting to do is definitely possible.

Comment: Can you share your Gruntfile.js?

Comment: Where are you OP ?!?!

Comment: Sorry my question was poor I have updated

Answer (score 4):

Some scripts need to be loaded in order.  Using the glob does not guarantee the correct order. Because of this, if the file array returned by the generic `concat` glob is in alphabetic order, `bootstrap.js` would be loaded before its dependencies.  That's no good!

I would change your concat block to look something like this:

```
concat:{
  dist:{
    src:[
          'dev-theme/js/modernizr.js',
          'dev-theme/js/bootstrap.js',
          'dev-theme/js/**/*.js'
        ],
    dest:'dev-theme/js/complete.js'
  }
},
```

If you aren't using the version of jQuery included with WordPress, you'd want to add that to the `src` list.